# Woocommerce plugin conflict with the theme

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, e-commerce, woocommerce-rest-api

I am new to Wordpress. I am trying to include plugin for credit card and PayPal payment gateway. So I installed Woocommerce. After installing when I try to activate it is showing the following error.
Below error I go in my email.

```
WordPress version 5.4.1 
Current theme: (version ) 
Current plugin: (version ) 
PHP version 7.2.19-5+bionic 
Error Details ============= 
An error of type E_COMPILE_ERROR was caused in line 739 of the file /var/www/html/wp- 
content/themes/../woo-functions.php. Error message: require(): Failed opening required 
'/var/www/html/wp-content/themes/../widget/vnt-woo-filter-price.php' (include_path='.:')
```

Please find below screenshot of my admin panel.
[image]

I have checked the woo-functions.php for line 739 is contains following code:

```
...
require get_template_directory() . '/widget/vnt-woo-filter-price.php';
...
```

Please help me in this. I am trying to solve from past few days.

Comment: It could be useful to share the code from the file where the error message comes from. 
The path to the file can be found in the error message

Comment: @7uc1f3r I have updated the question. pls check

Comment: Hi any help pls

Comment: **1)** does the referenced file exist?. **2)** 
just be patient until an answer comes [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/326569/under-what-circumstances-may-i-add-urgent-or-other-similar-phrases-to-my-quest)